# What is an effective way to backup data?

Tags: backup, video, images, data-transfer

I have a ton of stuff. Some of it is very old. One bizarre issue I run into when using android is that I can't copy or even see some of the oldest files when I plug the phone to a computer and open it for transferring files.

For some reason, the computer can't read or copy some files. There is no corruption or data loss because I can browse said files on the phone, open them or send them through Whatsapp.

Which is what I did last time. I have to back up a thousand photos so I send them through WhatsApp in batches of 50. Needless to say, that was quite annoying.

Is there some effective method/software of dumping all images and videos from the phone onto anything?

Why is there such a bizarre data reading issue any way?

Do I like need the android equivalent of shadowcopy or something ?

Comment: try [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) or [adb-sync](https://github.com/google/adb-sync), MTP has known issues with large amount of files

Answer (score 1):

> I have to back up a thousand photos

For backing up photos, I would use [Google Photos](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.photos&hl=en_GB). It's free, and it does it automatically (if that's enabled). It also has a ton of other features like sorting by people and pets, using Google Lens to copy text in the photo, and backed up photos are accessible on the [web version](https://photos.google.com).

Be careful though, as deleting a picture on the web version deletes it from the synced device as well, thanks to alecxs for mentioning this.

Comment: Google = no privacy!

Comment: Not necessarily. Plus, people share a huge amount of information with Google on a daily basis -- willingly!